# Re-invoking IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

Why is that code block throws an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: setSize is not defined"

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("#draw");

(function setSize() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
})();

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    setSize();
})
```

Comment: Why do you have it as a IFFE? Why not just use a normal function declaration statement? Afaik, function expressions don't bind to symbols external to themselves.

Comment: The whole reason you put something in an IFEE is so things like `setSize()` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Just define your `setSize` function and call it once (it should have the same effect as your IFFE).

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("#draw");

function setSize() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

setSize();

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    setSize();
})
```

Comment: I know i can do that, isn't it possible to create & invoke a function and make it available for re-invoking?

Comment: @OzturkCanGokkaya — Only through unintuitive hacks. Write clear code. Brevity stops being a virtue when it turns into a game of code golf.

Comment: As @Mark Meyer said, the whole purpose of IFFE is to "box" the content and make it UNAVAILABLE to other parts of the code.