# How can I call a high order function again in the code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, output, javascript-objects

```js
const x = { a:1 };

(function q({a}){
  console.log(a);
  return a;
})(x); // unable to execute

console.log(q(x))
```

I am unable to execute line 6. Why? In line 3 console is working if I remove line 6:

`Error: q is not defined`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-invoking IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893765/re-invoking-iife)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create multiple instances of IIFE Javascript module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147220/how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-iife-javascript-module)

Comment: tl;dr: Don't use an IIFE for this, just make a normal function and call it twice.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yes, it did.

Answer (score -1):

```
const x = { a:1 };
// This IIFE isn't assigned to a variable in global. No reference to the object
(function q({a}){
  console.log(a);
  return a;
})(x); // unable to execute
```

### console.log(q(x))

This works, but you cannot call it again since a was returned back into q and q is not a function:

```
const x = { a:1 };
// This IIFE isn't assigned to a variable in global. No reference to the object
const q = (function ({a}){
  console.log(a);
  return a;
})(x); // unable to execute



 console.log(q) // => 1
```